# Why do the members of a bridge lose their Ip address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, bridge

I have created a bridge using to existing network interfaces:

```
$ brctl addif br0 eth1
$ brctl addif br0 eth2
```

Why do `eth1` and `eth2` lose their IP addresses? What's the reasoning behind it?

PS this is on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a device is part of a bridge the IP address is set on the bridge rather than on the individual devices, because that is where packets can enter from the host system or exit to the host system.

A bridge is basically just a virtual ethernet switch with both the bridge device, and each device that is added to it, being a port on that switch. The bridge device (`br0` in this case) is then the switch port which is connected to your computer and which can be given an address and used to send and receive packets.

Comment: @TomH Could  you please elaborate a bit more? The packets must necessarily come in from the LAN to the bridge first (via `eth1` or `eth2` only, they being physical devices unlike the virtual `br0`), right?

Comment: Yes but because the device is part of a bridge it just passes the packets straight to the bridge device and it is the bridge device which introduces them to the IP stack.